# How to input array to another array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm a beginner in reactjs, I'm trying map array and insert the file into another array, and after insert, I map the file into the table, but I got Error "Maximum update depth exceeded"

This is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../Components.css";
import { MDBDataTable } from "mdbreact";
import AuthService from "../../Services/AuthService";
// import AuthService from "../Services/AuthService";

export default function Dataadmin() {
  const [Searchfile, setSearchfile] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    columns: [
      {
        label: "No",
        field: "no",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      {
        label: "Title",
        field: "title",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      {
        label: "Singer",
        field: "singer",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      {
        label: "Genre",
        field: "genre",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      {
        label: "Country",
        field: "country",
        sort: "asc",
      },
      {
        label: "Action",
        field: "action",
        sort: "asc",
      },
    ],
    rows: [],
  });
  AuthService.getalldata().then((res) => {
    setSearchfile(res.data);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Searchfile.map((item, index) => {
      const cloned = { ...data };
      cloned.rows.push({
        no: index + 1,
        title: item.title,
        singer: item.singer,
        genre: item.genre,
        country: item.country,
        action: (
          <>
            <button className="btn-action">
              <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
            </button>
            <button className="btn-action" style={{ marginLeft: "1vh" }}>
              <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </button>
          </>
        ),
      });
      setData(cloned);
    });
  }, [Searchfile, data]);
  return (
    <div className="div-admin">
      <div className="table-adminss">
        <MDBDataTable
          className="mytable-admin"
          striped
          bordered
          small
          data={data}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: This is the result]

Can someone explain to me why I get an error and how to fix it? , hope you guys understand what I'm asking :D

Comment: did you try to remove the `data` dependency from the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: remove data from the effect dependency and set it with the callback: `setData(data=>{const cloned={...data};other code; return cloned}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It causes because of you set setData inside a loop.**

One you can do, you can store the array inside a `const` and `setData(...data, *that const*)` outside of the loop. you don't need loop here actually. As far I know **MDDataTable** map data itself.

according to your code you can simply do it,

```
useEffect(() => {
      setData(...data, Searchfile) //if your Searchfile contains data
    });
  }, [Searchfile, data]);
```

Hope you got this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios in react in which a component re-renders

1. When the state changes (In this case, an example is searchFile,)
2. When the props changes ( The properties passed to the component)

The function

```
  AuthService.getalldata().then((res) => {
        setSearchfile(res.data);
      });
```

is called each time the component renders calling the `setSearchfile`. So once the `setSearchfile` is called the component re-renders once again calling the same function mentioned above`(Authservice.getAllData())`.This process repeats. So this will result in an infinite loop which the browser cannot handle. Hence you get the above error.

Moving the `(Authservice.getAllData())` into the method of `useEffect` should solve the maximum update depth exceeded.